# Is it possible to get all user id's who have shared a specific post, through facebook graph api or any other resource?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get all user id's who have shared a specific post, through graph api or any other resource?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: the bigger question is: what for do you need the information?